# Undo/RollBack latest query

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback

While updating my table tblTransaction I enter this code by mistake

```
update tblTransaction
set Total = 1100
```

And now all the value in that column has become 1100. Then I tried this code to rollback

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
rollback transaction;
```

Even though rollback code was executed but it didn't Work. So, how can I revert this total column value to it's previous value?

[image]

Comment: You can restore a backed up copy of the database.

Comment: It's already too late; you can't `BEGIN` a **new** transaction and expect a `ROLLBACK` to effect both your *new* transaction and your prior implicit transaction. If you don't have a history table, then you'll going to want to get a copy of your backup, and `RESTORE` it (either over the existing database, or to a new one, and then `UPDATE` the rows in your production database). Then **learn** from your mistake; check your code before you go updating *every* row in your table.

Comment: My suspicion is that Total should be UnitPrice * Quantity.  In which case `UPDATE tblTransaction SET Total = Quantity * UnitPrice` should work for you.

Comment: Then when can i use RollBack? @Larnu

Comment: When you have an uncommitted transaction, @Awesome, either implicit or explicit. `ROLLBACK` has no effect on a committed transaction; it's already committed.

Comment: You could think of it like this: You initially write your changes in pencil, and then in Pen. Before you write it in Pen, you could use an eraser to remove the pencil, undoing any changes, but once you write it in pen the eraser is useless. Once a transaction is committed, it's written in Pen.

Comment: If that is the case, @JonathanWillcock , the OP would be even better off by using a computed column.

Comment: I reckon this is a mistake every DBA makes once... DataGrip actually has a check for `UPDATE` with no `WHERE` and asks to confirm